# React-Admin linking two fields

Tags: react-admin

I am trying to use React-Admin [tutorial](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs) covering how to link to inputs without success.

I have a API endpoint that has users and each user has multiple accounts. I want to create an Edit/Create form where you can choose a user then from next field dropdown to have possibility to select an account that user has (values can be 0, 1, ..n accounts).

```
<SimpleForm toolbar={<MyToolbar />}>
<ReferenceInput label="User Name:" source="Id" reference="users" {...rest}>
<AutocompleteInput optionText="User.name" {...rest}/>
</ReferenceInput>


  <FormDataConsumer>
               {({ formData, ...rest }) => (
                   <SelectInput
                       source="users"
                       optionText="Account"
                       choices={
                           formData.user.Id
                              
                       }
                       {...rest}
                   />
               )}
           </FormDataConsumer>

</SimpleForm>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works just like in react-admin documentation; problem was in my custom API as I did not implement all filters, options etc on getList type of calls.